# Why does fortran child cause mpi4py error when spawning?

Tags: python, fortran, mpi, mpi4py, intel-mpi

I have an mpi4py python code that spawns a Fortran executable.

The code prceeds happily enough, spawning and disconnecting from the Fortran child - however occasionally the code fails with the following error:

```
Abort(3188623) on node 0 (rank 0 in comm 0): Fatal error in PMPI_Init: Other MPI error, error stack:
MPIR_Init_thread(703)..........:
MPID_Init(958).................:
MPIDI_OFI_mpi_init_hook(1499)..:
MPID_Comm_connect(250).........:
MPIDI_OFI_mpi_comm_connect(655):
dynproc_exchange_map(534)......:
(unknown)(): Other MPI error
```

I'm unable to find out much about what this error means and why it happens, but it happens when attempting a spawn.

Has anyone seen this error before using mpi4py and know why it might happen?

I'm using the intel mpi and compilers (Parallel studio XE cluster: intel_2020/compilers_and_libraries_2020.0.166), python 3.6.9 and mpi4py 3.0.3.

Comment: This is some kind of generic error  reported by the MPI library. Unfortunately,you do not say which MPI library you are using.

Comment: The MPI I am using is intel mpi, and part of the parallel studio - updated the question to make this clear.

Comment: I suggest to contact the Intel official support forum https://community.intel.com/ They should have a section about Intel MPI. I also suggest to test starting normal MPI programs (without Python). Does it happen for them or not?

Comment: Yeah, I'll contact Intel. Normal MPI programs run fine, no issues.